# List of comment templates

Tags: discussion, comment, big-list

*Inspired by [this question on meta.cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/comment-templates). The post [at meta.Tex.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) is quite impressive.*

We often leave generic comments to OP and answer posters such as "*if this is a homework, please add a tag,*" and such. Can we make this post a community wiki and add a big list of standard comments? Let's annotate the usage cases, so other users and copy-and-paste whenever applies.

As usual on meta, (down/up)vote if you (dis/)agree.

To facilitate easy copying, if your comment contains links and/or formatting, please enclose the whole text between single [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) characters <kbd>`</kbd> to type your answer verbatim `like this`

Comment: The one used often for homework is in [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4155).

Comment: I think it is basically the same idea as given in a different discussion some time ago: [CFV: Proposal for standardized meta-comments, to avoid main-site meta discussions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/cfv-proposal-for-standardized-meta-comments-to-avoid-main-site-meta-discussion). It received plenty of upvotes, but nothing was done.

Comment: I've added some comments I've been using. (And by doing that I've also given some examples of situations, for which I consider such comments comments useful.) I thinks it goes without saying that other users should feel free to change them or even rewrite them completely. (It is implied by the nature of CW, but I wanted to stress this. Be bold!)

Comment: Perhaps we could modify some of the templates given at [cstheory](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/comment-templates).
I went through their list and at least these situations appear at our site, too: 
"Question lacks motivation/background",
"User crossposts a question on multiple sites",
"User posts answer as comment",
"User posts a question that is off-topic but may be on-topic on another site".

Comment: I suppose a link to the [AutoReviewComments script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) would also be useful here.

Comment: In need of a comment template to ask author of an answer to consider rewriting answer in more understandable way, removing his/her personal opinion. [Example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1299166/45937)

Comment: Unfortunately, repeatedly using comment templates undermines the reason for their use, in the first place. I can sniff a "generic, robotic, predetermined  comment" a mile away, and so can most users, askers and answerers alike.  And relying on templates to "rubber stamp" a post with a comment template is just plain lazy. If you feel the need to address the OP, address him/her directly and specifically regarding the the post at hand.  If you're too lazy to do that, don't comment at all.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136609/295232) is a list of comments used network-wide (though some of them are explicitly Stack Overflow minded).

Comment: @amWhy Eh, true.  On the other hand, if one is not to directly use the below comment templates, it is worth noting that the links are quite useful.

Answer (score 50):

**Welcome to MSE**

This is based a comment Arturo used to add to questions of relatively new users (although this post has been edited a few times and the message has been slightly modified):

> Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

`Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.`

Of course, this should be customized for the particular post. In particular, the examples of imperative words should come from the question itself. And you could throw in a sentence saying "Titles should be informative".

Comment: It's not the imperative as a grammatical device that's rude -- the standard style of written mathematics uses imperatives all over the place. What _is_ rude is writing a question that looks like it consists only of a verbatim quote from an exercise sheet with no thought of the asker's own to go with it. But the fact that such quotes usually contain imperative verbs is completely incidental.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Feel free to rewrite and improve the template - that's why it is CW. (And I should also say that I agree with your point.)

Comment: It would be impossible for me to rewrite the comment here without making a lie of the attribution to Arturo. But if you can find something Arturo wrote _without_ the ridiculous, misleading comment about imperatives, I would be all for replacing this with it.

Comment: @Henning Something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136094/how-to-obtain-all-the-solution-for-this-diophantine-equation#comment313483_136094)? (I am not entirely sure that Arturo was the first person to use welcome comment similar to above, but at least I have seen him using it plenty of times.)

Comment: I have removed the part mentioning homework tag. I had some doubts whether I should include link to [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) instead.

Comment: I've often been tempted when seeing someone give nothing but "Prove blah" as a post to leave a comment of "No." I don't, but I'm tempted! :)

Comment: `Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!`$\quad$

Answer (score 42):

**Accepting answers**

> After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

`After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).`

Comment: what if it is a community wiki?>

Comment: @RE60K I would comment this anyways.

Comment: Is it socially acceptable to comment this if you are the answerer?

Comment: @StellaBiderman There are some post on meta on this. For example, [Is it wrong to ask a user to accept an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6984) and some of the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6984). Perhaps this is the closest to your inquiry: [Is it bad form to ask the OP to officially accept your answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20461)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think this can be improved;  there was a recent meta post, and additional links to other ideas for an appropriate comment, and I will help if you'd like me to.  What concerns me is: "... if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it."  It refers to the acceptance of one acceptable answer.  It does not address that if there is more than one answer, and more than one acceptable answer, one can only accept one answer, (though, with enough rep, they can upvote any/all answers they've found helpful).

Comment: As written, it could likely give the wrong impression that all answers one receives can be "accepted" if "acceptable."  Or perhaps, since  we need a brief comment, because only so much can be said in a comment template, a link can be provided to the the image of a question an how to accept a question.  Anyway, I'll give some more thought on this.

Comment: “After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it.” This instruction is often followed, which typically results in the first answer being  accepted while a better (but later) answer is not so rewarded. Better advice would be to wait and see what answers roll in, and then pick the best one.

Comment: @JohnBentin I would guess that typical use of *this* comment template is when somebody sees that a user haven't accepted any answer after a longer period of time. (What is the appropriate time to wait is, of course, a judgement call and different users might have different criteria.)

Comment: `Welcome to this site! If the issue has been resolved, do consider [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers: this signals resolution, prevents the page from being bumped, scores points, and influences the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.`$\quad$

Comment: `Welcome to this site! [Accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers are good ways to say thanks; these actions signal resolution, prevent the page from being bumped, score points, and influence the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.`$\quad$

Comment: `Welcome to this site! Users who [accept ✔ good answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to their past questions are more likely to have their future questions answered.`$\quad$

Answer (score 39):

**How to write math**

This might be added as a pointer where to find help:

> For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

`For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).`

Or a comment with detailed description:

> For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

`For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).`

Sometimes this explanation can be added if a post was TeX-ified by other MSE users:

> Some MSE users tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: I have moved link to [help](/help/notation) to the first place. (It contains links to two of the three remaining links.)

Comment: The ["here" usage is ill-advised on User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/12130/92668). Perhaps this template could use more context-specific words?

Comment: @Therkel, I've edited it, but frankly I would just link to the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/276406) and skip the rest.  It's the best reference by far.  However, since the /help/notation page links to it and is a more "official" part of the site, probably we should stick with that one.

Comment: @Wildcard When editing comment templates, it is good to edit also the part where people copy-and-paste the text from, not only the preview. (I edited the post so that it contains both versions. Feel free to edit it further.) About linking just the tutorial - at least [some users](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2957/faq-on-typesetting-of-formulae-hard-to-find/2958#comment13382_2958) think that the tutorial is probably not ideal (but it's the only tutorial we have here on meta).

Answer (score 38):

**A new user who posts a pure homework question:**

Another version of something to say to a new user who posts a pure homework question:
Context:  I didn't actually know this thread was here, so I typed this up on the fly as something appropriate.  Since someone who's been here way longer than I thought it would be useful here and suggested I post it here, I will!

> Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

`Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.`

Comment: Thanks Alan!  I will certainly use this next time I want this kind of comment.

Comment: ...and a comment for others reading this: the reason I like it is that it makes the point that people seeking help here should be prepared to treat it as a two-way street and put in some effort themselves.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add a link to the [good question thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351). The more often it appears, the more likely it becomes that people will click it and learn.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Good idea,  thanks!

Comment: I've changed "exercise" to "question" to avoid the all-to-frequent "it's not an exercise" response.

Answer (score 35):

**This question is of insufficient quality** *(Template arose from [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement))*

If necessary, this can be preceded by *Hello, welcome to Math.SE*.

> Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

`Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.`

Comment: That template appears to still be in the process of editing and discussion, under the posting by Lord Farin.  If LF does not incorporate the new suggestions it is likely there will be a separate thread to finish the edits.  In addition to the comment text editing, there is either a plan or an undisputed request to have the "This" link eventually point to a "how to post good question" meta question and not to the "how to post homework question" that currently exists.

Comment: @zyx I edited a link to the other thread and included your comment about the ongoing discussion. Feel free to improve this community wiki post here once you have reached an agreement on the other thread.

Comment: I have the feeling LF might be tired of making edits on this constantly, so having a CW thread could make sense to let whoever wants to influence the text. It is potentially going to be used on thousands of questions.  Then update this answer when it converges.

Comment: I was indeed tired for a few days; back now. The comment has gone through five successively smaller edit rounds. With two weeks of time to assess it having passed, I doubt there will be many people requesting further changes to it. IMO, the only thing that is still pending is a "good question" meta post.

Answer (score 25):

**Tags that are frequently used incorrectly**

- **Sum of Squares**

> The [sums-of-squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sums-of-squares) tag is for questions about representations of integers as sums of squares, see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sums-of-squares/info) and [relevant discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12411/what-is-the-tag-sums-of-squares-intended-for).

`The ([tag:sums-of-squares]) tag is for questions about representations of integers as sums of squares, see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sums-of-squares/info) and [relevant discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12411/what-is-the-tag-sums-of-squares-intended-for).`

- **Theorem Provers**

> The tag [theorem-provers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theorem-provers) is for questions about software designed for checking formal proofs or assisting with writing them, see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about proofs of theorems.

`The tag ([tag:theorem-provers]) is for questions about software designed for checking formal proofs or assisting with writing them, see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about proofs of theorems.`

- **Formal Proofs**

> The tag [formal-proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-proofs) is for questions about proofs in various formal systems (e.g., natural deduction or Hilbert system), see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-proofs/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about rigorous mathematical proofs.

`The tag ([tag:formal-proofs]) is for questions about proofs in various formal systems (e.g., natural deduction or Hilbert system), see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-proofs/info). It is not intended for all questions which are about rigorous mathematical proofs.`

- **Proof Theory**

> The tag [proof-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-theory) is intended for questions about proof theory as a branch of mathematical logic, see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-theory/info) and relevant [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/the-proof-theory-tag-is-misused-too-often). It is not intended for all questions related to proofs.

`The tag ([tag:proof-theory]) is intended for questions about proof theory as a branch of mathematical logic, see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-theory/info) and relevant [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/the-proof-theory-tag-is-misused-too-often). It is not intended for all questions related to proofs.`

- **Summation and Sequences-and-Series**

> The tag [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation) is supposed to be about finite sums (see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/info).) The tag [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) is for infinite series.

`The tag ([tag:summation]) is supposed to be about finite sums (see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/info).) The tag ([tag:sequences-and-series]) is for infinite series.`

- **Algebraic Geometry**

> The tag [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry) is intended for questions in a branch of mathematics called algebraic geometry (see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebraic-geometry/info).) The tags [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) and/or [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) should be used for basic problems that involve both algebra and geometry.

`The tag ([tag:algebraic-geometry]) is intended for questions in a branch of mathematics called algebraic geometry (see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebraic-geometry/info).) The tags ([tag:algebra-precalculus]) and/or ([tag:geometry]) should be used for basic problems that involve both algebra and geometry.`

- **Complex Geometry**

> The tag [complex-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-geometry) is intended for questions about complex manifolds, see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/complex-geometry/info). In particular, this tag is not suitable for questions about basic properties of complex numbers.

`The tag ([tag:complex-geometry]) is intended for questions about complex manifolds, see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/complex-geometry/info). In particular, this tag is not suitable for questions about basic properties of complex numbers.`

- **Integral domain for Integration**

> An [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) is a commutative ring with no zero divisors. The tag [integral-domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-domain) should be used for questions about such rings, not for questions about integration.

`An [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) is a commutative ring with no zero divisors. The tag ([tag:integral-domain]) should be used for questions about such rings, not for questions about integration.`

- **Probability theory for Probability**

> [Probability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is about the measure-theoretic foundations of stochastics. The tag [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about  calculating a specific probability. Use [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) instead, see also [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/the-tags-probability-and-probability-theory).

`[Probability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is about the measure-theoretic foundations of stochastics. The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about  calculating a specific probability. Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/the-tags-probability-and-probability-theory).`

- **Roots and arithmetic or radicals**

> The tag [roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots) is for zeroes of functions, the tags [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) and [radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals) are better tags for questions about square roots, cube roots, etc. From [roots tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info): For questions about "square roots", "cube roots", and such, consider using the (radicals) and (arithmetic) tags.

`The tag ([tag:roots]) is for zeroes of functions, the tags ([tag:arithmetic]) and ([tag:radicals]) are better tags for questions about square roots, cube roots, etc. From [roots tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info): For questions about "square roots", "cube roots", and such, consider using the (radicals) and (arithmetic) tags.`

- **Filters**

> The tag [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) is intended for [filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29) in set-theoretical and order-theoretical sense; see the [tag description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/filters/info).

`The tag ([tag:filters]) is intended for [filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29) in set-theoretical and order-theoretical sense; see the [tag description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/filters/info).`

I have added this mainly because people keep using this tag in connection with Kalman filter and similar stuff. See also [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16992/about-kalman-filter-tag).

- **Dimension theory**

> The tag [dimension-theory-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimension-theory-algebra) is not intended for questions about dimension of vector spaces from linear algebra, see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/dimension-theory-algebra/info) for more details.

`The tag ([tag:dimension-theory-algebra]) is not intended for questions about dimension of vector spaces from linear algebra, see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/dimension-theory-algebra/info) for more details.`

- **Euler's constant and Euler's number**

> The tag [euler-mascheroni-constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-mascheroni-constant) is intended for questions about [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$, see the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/eulers-constant/info). For questions about [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) $e$ you can use the tag [eulers-number-e](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eulers-number-e).

`The tag ([tag:euler-mascheroni-constant]) is intended for questions about [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$, see the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/eulers-constant/info). For questions about [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) $e$ you can use the tag ([tag:eulers-number-e]).`

- **Intersection theory**

> The tag [intersection-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intersection-theory) is for the question about a branch of algebraic geometry called [intersection theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory). It is not for questions about intersections of sets, calculating intersections of two lines and other similar questions.

`The tag ([tag:intersection-theory]) is for the question about a branch of algebraic geometry called [intersection theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory). It is not for questions about intersections of sets, calculating intersections of two lines and other similar questions.`

- **Independence**

> The tag [independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) is for question about independent events in probability theory, see the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/independence/info).

`The tag ([tag:independence]) is for question about independent events in probability theory, see the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/independence/info).`

- **Functional Equations and Functional Analysis**

> The tag [functional-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis) is intended for questions about infinite dimensional vector spaces, there is a separate tag for [functional-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-equations); see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functional-analysis/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

`The tag ([tag:functional-analysis]) is intended for questions about infinite dimensional vector spaces, there is a separate tag for ([tag:functional-equations]); see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functional-analysis/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)`

**Logic**

The tag [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) should be used for questions about [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/logic/info).

`The tag ([tag:logic]) should be used for questions about [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), see [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/logic/info).`

Comment: Is there a reason to have the extra set of parentheses around the `tag:` links? It seems unnecessary to me, but I want to make sure before I remove them.

Comment: @epimorphic: They are probably there because in comments  `[tag:tagname]` is rendered as [tag:tagname], without the parentheses. The added parentheses make them look more like tag links in posts: `([tag:tagname])` becomes ([tag:tagname]).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Ah, silly me. Though perhaps the additional parentheses should still be removed from the comment previews above.

Comment: @epimorphic: That would seem to be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @epimorphic As Arthur Fischer writes, I have included them because ([tag:filters]) makes clear to the reader that this represents a tag. But [tag:filters] would probably work just fine. As for preview, I included in both places exactly the same text. Maybe you are right that we should make an effort to make rendering look line in comments, not like in posts. But I do not see other comment templates than those about tags where there is a difference. Basically I see this as a non-issue.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The "should" in my last comment might have been poorly worded – I meant it as a suggestion. It's not that big of a deal as you say, and using the same code in both places is probably easier to maintain.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think ([tag:dimension-theory]) is unavailable. But I have noticed many users incorrectly using the tag ([tag:dimension-theory-algebra]). Maybe replace ([tag:dimension-theory]) with ([tag:dimension-theory-algebra])?

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Yes, the tag (dimension-theory) was replaced by those two tags, as discussed here: [Should we divide (dimension-theory) into 2 tags, one for topology, and one for algebra?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30109) I have edited the template following your suggestion. (Feel free to edit it further, if needed.)

Comment: There is a separate answer with a template related to the (problem-solving) tag: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/33112#33112

Answer (score 23):

**More descriptive/informative titles**

> Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
>   From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

`Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).`

For a slightly shorter version, and with a link to the newer "How to ask a good question" question, you can also use :

> Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)

`Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)`

Depending on the case, one could remove the sentence in parentheses, or use it to point to a different part of the linked answer if it is more relevant, such as "MathJax works in titles" or "Don't be afraid to make the title long".

Comment: I think one could even remove the last sentence (between the parentheses), as the answer as a whole is relevant. Alternatively, one could point to specific parts of the answer depending on the situation. For the example given in the template, pointing out that MathJax works in the title can be more useful, as explicitly writing the equation/inequality/formula is always more informative than just mentioning it.

Answer (score 22):

**Welcome/LaTeX help/Homework question**

Something like this is useful when a new user asks what is almost surely a  homework question without formatting anything into LaTeX.

> Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking *effective* homework-related questions. Cheers!

`Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!`

---

Here's a slightly shorter version that cuts straight to the point:

> Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. For formatting help, See: [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!

`Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. For formatting help, See: [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!`

Comment: @Hanno As far as I can tell, both `[faq]` and `[tour]` are one of the [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) and they work in comments without the need to use `[text](url)` format: [faq] and [tour]. (There is a minor advantage to keeping the comment template a bit shorter - if possible; it's useful in cases when the commenter wants to add something more to the copied template text.)

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak for pointing out this! I just deployed this template comment in 'Daily math SE life' & wanted to make sure the link is not broken ... $\ddot\smile$
I shall rollback the edit in a moment.

Answer (score 21):

**Multiple questions in one post**

> Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

`Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).`

Comment: We can type this much every time  we need to.:)

Answer (score 17):

**Gender Neutral Language**

> Not everyone who does mathematics is a man. Consider using gender neutral language such as "they" and "person" instead of "he" and "sir" when talking about other users.

`Not everyone who does mathematics is a man. Consider using gender neutral language such as "they" and "person" instead of "he" and "sir" when talking about other users.`

Answer (score 16):

**Do not use images to ask your question**

> Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

`Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.`

If you edited the question to remove the picture, consider adding an extra sentence:

> Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

`Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.`

(Even though it doesn't show here, `[edit]` when used in comments turns into a link for editing the post the comment pertains to.)

Comment: Tbh, I'm not even sure what a screen reader is, but I'll leave it in just to be safe.

Comment: Think we should include "may not be legible" in this?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Feel free to make changes -- it's a community wiki post after all :)

Comment: A screen reader is a program that read text of the screen and converts it to audio. I'm not sure if many work for equations.

Answer (score 16):

### A more constructive comment for promoting better questions.

> I would like to inform you that while Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, [more than just a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.

`I would like to inform you that while Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, [more than just a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.`

Answer (score 14):

**Write a good question: please add context**

This comment seems to get a better reception in the fortnight or so I (LF) have been using this than the "insufficient quality" version, and is considerably shorter. I haven't used the "insufficient quality" blurb since I wrote up this one (mainly to reflect the new close reason).

> Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

`Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.`

Answer (score 14):

**For answers to low-quality questions**

It is explained in [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) that (and why) users answering low-quality questions should (politely!) be reminded of the policies regarding quality on this site. The following comment template [was suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=57904709#57904709) by Xander Henderson:

> This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

`This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.`

Comment: I seem to be getting negative responses when pasting this template. I have a feeling the reason might be the use of the rhetoric question which may unfortunately sometimes put people in a defensive position. I suggest changing the relevant part of the template to "Instead of answering it, most often it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or to help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements."

Comment: @Snaw: This is a CW answer and everybody can edit it. However, I did not make that experience, and I personally find the phrase “most often it would be better” too vague. What are the exceptions, in which a bad question should be answered?

Comment: @Snaw: Of course all these templates are just *suggestions.* (I have a text file on my computer with the most important comments, taken from here and elsewhere, modified as I found it appropriate, ready for copy/paste.)

Comment: I think you're right, then maybe "Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or to help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements"? I realize this is CW but I didn't know if I should edit it on my own without asking for the opinion of others. Yeah, I should probably keep a text file like this as well, but I guess out of laziness I keep coming back to this page.

Comment: @Snaw: I have no problems with your last suggestion, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 12):

Similar to **How to write math** by Martin Sleziak, but a little more focus on the fact, that one self has edited a post.

> Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

`Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.`

Comment: Is there any particular reason it is spelled “Tex” and not “TeX” or “$\TeX$”?

Answer (score 12):

**Formatting of title to limit usage of vertical space**

Some -- especially new -- users employ display math mode (using `$$` delimiters) and other TeX commands (e.g. `\dfrac`, `\displaystyle`) in their titles. After fixing this, the following comment can be used to explain one's actions.

> I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

`I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.`

Answer (score 11):

**Please convert comment to an answer/self-answer your question**

> @... Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

`@... Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).`

Or in the case the OP has found the answer (through the comments):

> @... If you found the answer to your question, please consider self-answering your question, so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

`@... If you found the answer to your question, please consider self-answering your question, so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).`

Answer (score 9):

**Meta-tags are not supposed to be used standalone**

Big-list:

> [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/big-list/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

`[tag:big-list] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/big-list/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).`

---

Reference-request:

> [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

`[tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).`

Comment: I would suggest that, rather than using this comment, you should simply add one or more appropriate tags unilaterally.

Comment: @Nate I think that it might be helpful (especially to inexperienced users) if the reasons for retagging are explained in a comment.

Comment: ...or, if not in a comment, then at least in edit summary.

Answer (score 9):

**Self-promotion and link-only answers**

> Please note if you want to promote your own website/blog/text you *should disclose your affiliation*, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. 
>   For more details, see [How not to be a spammer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

`Please note if you want to promote your own website/blog/text you *should disclose your affiliation*, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. 
For more details, see [How not to be a spammer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).`

> Just linking to your own website is not a good answer. Linking to it, posting at least an outline of all steps needed to solve the problem, and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

`Just linking to your own website is not a good answer. Linking to it, posting at least an outline of all steps needed to solve the problem, and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)`

Answer (score 8):

**Do not use titles consisting of TeX only**

> Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8891).

`Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8891).`

Or if you prefer to give a link which has more information on how to format titles:

> Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

`Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).`

Answer (score 7):

**Be cautious with creating new tags**

> From [FAQ about tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/128#128): *Try to avoid creating new tags. Instead, check if there is some synonym that already has a popular tag.* It's not easy to keep balance between too specific tags and not having enough tags, but it is always good to search first and to ask yourself, whether newly created tag is not too specific. (Of course, you can disagree with the removal of the tag you've created, and there is possibility for further discussion, if needed.)

`From [FAQ about tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/128#128): *Try to avoid creating new tags. Instead, check if there is some synonym that already has a popular tag.* It's not easy to keep balance between too specific tags and not having enough tags, but it is always good to search first and to ask yourself, whether newly created tag is not too specific. (Of course, you can disagree with the removal of the tag you've created, and there is possibility for further discussion, if needed.)`

The first part of the comment seems to be sufficient in cases when retagging or removal of tags is clear-cut.

Answer (score 7):

**For users (especially new users) who post homework-style questions**

> Questions posted to math.stackexchange.com should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. That can make people wonder if someone copied a question without understanding it. You can ask for help understanding a question, or you can say specifically what difficulties you had solving a problem, but merely copying is frowned on.

`Questions posted to math.stackexchange.com should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. That can make people wonder if someone copied a question without understanding it. You can ask for help understanding a question, or you can say specifically what difficulties you had solving a problem, but merely copying is frowned on.`

This can be used when a question reads something like this:

Consider the quadratic equation $x^2 + 2x + 9 = 0$.

**(a)** Find the discriminant.

**(b)** Prove that the roots are not transcendental numbers.

**(c)** Factor the polynomial.

Comment: There are already templates for this style of comment [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4932#4932), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/9407#9407), and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/19973#19973).

Comment: @T.Bongers I do not see a problem with having several templates which cam be used in similar situations. If some users prefer this wording, they can use this one.

Answer (score 6):

**New users who do not have enough reputation posting comments in the answers section**

> Welcome to Math.SE! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

`Welcome to Math.SE! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).`

**New users posting another question in the answers section**

> Welcome to Math.SE! This does not provide an answer to the question. You should ask [a separate question about your concern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you provide some background and formalize it as a mathematical problem.

`Welcome to Math.SE! This does not provide an answer to the question. You should ask [a separate question about your concern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you provide some background and formalize it as a mathematical problem.`

Adapted from 40 votes' comment.

Comment: I often see this comment posted, and don't understand why it is posted when most of the generic message is usually not relevant to the "answer" being commented on.  I find generic messages especially off-putting when they are largely irrelevant.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think it does not come from these templates, but from the Low Quality queue dialog for answers. It's true that the comment is often not applicable at all. Perhaps some reviewers don't realize that "no comment needed" is a perfectly good option.

Comment: @900sit-ups: That is helpful, thanks!  I haven't yet familiarized myself with all of the reviewing mechanisms. (Off-topic: I was really surprised to receive a reply to my comment so quickly by someone other than the post owner.  How did you do that?)

Comment: @JonasMeyer One of my Chrome extensions for SE is [Comments in Sidebar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/comments-in-sidebar/fojkncjknkcndbglhlfaenlkngflapeb): I see all recent comments on the site in the sidebar. On the main this is usually useless, on meta this is often irritating, but also helpful -- for example, when SE developers tracking bugs seek clarification on ancient bug reports from users who are no longer active.

Answer (score 6):

**Question closed - with explanation how it can reopened**

> Your question was closed, you should see a message at the top explaining why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that if you check the box "This edit resolves the original close reason", then your post will be put in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed.

`Your question was closed, you should see a message at the top explaining why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that if you check the box "This edit resolves the original close reason", then your post will be put in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed.`

**The same template with link to faq item on providing context**

> Your question was closed, you should see a message at the top explaining why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that if you check the box "This edit resolves the original close reason", then your post will be added to the review queue, where other users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed.

`Your question was closed, you should see a message at the top explaining why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that if you check the box "This edit resolves the original close reason", then your post will be added to the review queue, where other users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed.`

Comment: Creation of this template was prompted by Willie Wong saying [in a related post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821): *Perhaps this should also be made better known to the poster! Quite frequently I've seen inessential edits bump questions into the review queue, well before they are ready to be reconsidered.* The post is CW, if you have an idea how to improve the wording, please, edit it.

Comment: I'd really prefer that the "reopen requests" thread not be included in this. Ideally that thread should be reserved for more clear-cut cases, and advertising this thread will likely result in a lot of re-open requests for poor questions which haven't been improved. (The moderators regularly receive flags requesting the re-opening of such questions.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer I followed your advice and removed the part about the reopen request thread. (But it would be good not to remove your comment, so that other users who edit this template see that this was done on purpose.)

Comment: I don't see this comment much. But as of now, 'every edit' does not send the question to the reopen queue. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183233

Comment: @ACB I have tried to edit it a bit more to reflect the current state. (The post is CW - so it goes without saying that further improvements are welcome.)

Answer (score 4):

**Making user aware of monthly/daily quotas**

> I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, the Stack Exchange software will not allow you to do so.)
> For more details see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

`I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, the Stack Exchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).`

Of course, sometimes it might be better to be more specific. (E.g. "I've noticed that you've asked 10 questions in last 3 days" or something similar.)

Answer (score 3):

**Avoid the question ban**

> Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

`Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!`

Hopefully knowing the consequences will help promote better questions.

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

`Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!`

I have this saved as a keyboard shortcut under `htagq`.

Comment: Double post...?

Comment: That's weird. I have no idea how that happened.

Comment: In the event you like shorter URL's, use `http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ`.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sweet! Thanks

Comment: If you wish, here's the link relating to homework problems: https://goo.gl/Fyfb22

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt How do you make short links like those?

Comment: [Google's URL shortener](https://goo.gl).

Answer (score 2):

**Misused tag problem-solving**

> Do you need to solve a problem? That's what this site is all about, but please, don't use the tag [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) to tell us that. Use that tag only if you have a specific type of problem and you are asking for a way of thinking needed to solve those problems in general.

`Do you need to solve a problem? That's what this site is all about, but please, don't use the tag [tag:problem-solving] to tell us that. Use that tag only if you have a specific type of problem and you are asking for a way of thinking needed to solve those problems in general.`

Comment: There is an answer which collects various templates related to incorrectly used tags: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/8587#8587 Since this was posted as a separate answer, I have mentioned it at least in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

### For questions that should be on MathOverflow

> Given the rather advanced nature of the mathematics of this question, I think it would be more appropriately posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). If you agree, you can click on *flag* near the bottom left of your question, then on *in need of moderator intervention* and request that a moderator migrate the question to MathOverflow.

`> Given the rather advanced nature of the mathematics of this question, I think it would be more appropriately posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). If you agree, you can click on *flag* near the bottom left of your question, then on *in need of moderator intervention* and request that a moderator migrate the question to MathOverflow.`

Comment: I hope that only users who are regulars on MathOverflow would feel confident enough to post this comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Here’s how to ask a good question.**

Credit goes to @jjagmath for this comment template.

@jjagmath always uses this templete to  (mostly new) users post a question that does not know/follow the rules of this site when asking a question (although recently, last month, if @jjagmath uses this comment, the question is almost always deleted around six hours after @jjagmath posted this templete, although this most likely a coincidence):

> Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

> `Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.`

The following templete is always used by @jjagmath if the question does not have context or effort and the question is likely a homework:

> Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

`Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.`