# Is it wrong to ask a user to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepted-answer, accept-rate

I have seen several instances of questions which have at least one complete answer, but none of which are accepted, and no comments have been made to indicate why the user has not accepted an answer. Sometimes this is because the user asked one question and never returned after getting the answer they were looking for. However, there are instances where the user is still active, just with a low acceptance rate.

> In this situation, is it rude to comment on such a question, asking the user to accept one of the answers, or edit the question to indicate what they feel is missing?

Comment: I would say that it is quite common to do this, we even have a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945) for that specific purpose.

Comment: Before you comment asking the user to accept one of the answers, make sure there is at least one good answer there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my opinion, if the user *specifically* comments on your answer being very helpful, or the greatest, I think it is lovely to ask the user to accept your answer if they find it the most helpful.

Keep in mind the accept rate: There might be a reason that the answer has not been accepted if you see a high accept rate.

If you see a low accept rate, browse a couple of the user's questions and check if there are other decent answers that have not been accepted.

Well, if your answer is very good, and you think that it is the best amongst the others, then politely informing the user about how the answer should be accepted if it  is helpful is O.K.!

To conclude with, I just want to encourage all of the users here to post very attractive answers and they would be loved amongst the askers.

Comment: "and you think that it is best amongst the others"--maybe I'm uptight, but it generally seems more tactful to leave others to decide that (although if there are things bad or incorrect about other answers it should be pointed out, voted on (although I'm extra hesitant to downvote on "competing" answers due to potential bias), etc.). Comments asking for acceptance *might* be helpful for users who don't know about it yet, but to me it often induces mild eye rolling.

Comment: Note to newcomers – back in 2012, the site had something called "accept rate", to which Parth Kohli is referring, but that statistic passed on some years ago.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, then you just say, "Great, glad it was helpful!  Please accept an answer with the checkmark to the left (either my answer or another one) so the question is marked as 'resolved' in the system."  Or something like that.

Comment: @Wildcard: I am not sure what "the question is marked as 'resolved'". means.There is an "unanswered" designation that is only for questions with no answers with positive scores. So the acceptance would only resolve that if the answer (or some answer) didn't already have a score of 1 or higher. Maybe that is common?Perhaps you also refer to the different coloration that shows the question has an accepted answer when you happen to see it in a list? I like your wording better, and agree that generally accepting some good thorough answer is good, but typically don't see the point in requesting it.