# LaTeX and capitalization in titles

Tags: support, titles

This is probably a duplicate...

**Question 1**

I'm often asked to review edits made by users with even less reputation than I. Many of these edits texify titles. But on [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/660) it's written

> Ensure that the title contains some actual words, and not only $\LaTeX$ -- the search functionality of MSE does not interact well with typeset mathematics, making questions comprising only $\LaTeX$ (much) harder to find. Furthermore, the MathJax context menu (which pops up when you right-click on some typeset expression) overrides the browser's link context menu, making e.g. opening the question in a new tab difficult.

I this policy still in force?

**Question 2**

It seems to me MSE policy is to start the title of a question, as often as possible, with an upper case letter. Is it so? (I, personally, tend to start with an upper case letter when the title of the question is a sentence, ending with a period of a question mark, and to use lower case letters otherwise, but I don't mind changing!)

**Question 3**

Where are users supposed to find answers to such questions?

Comment: This is also related: [How to ask a good question? - A good title](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144). (Ant this may, to some extent, answer question 3: Where are users supposed to find answers to such questions?)

Comment: You should never start a sentence with a symbol. **Bad:** *2 is a number*. **Good:** *Two is a number*. **Bad:** *$\int\sin x dx$: how to work it out?* **Good:** *How do I work out $\int\sin x dx$?* (This is maths, not Math.SE.)

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Capitalizing titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I this policy still in force?

I'll put it this way: *this is still a good idea*. Makes it easier for folks to do the right-click -> new tab maneuver.  Makes titles easier to understand. Makes them more mobile-friendly: the page width is smaller there, and formulas don't linebreak as gracefully as text. Finally, having some text in titles makes them  look less like   gobbledygook to Google; I suspect Google may distrust the pages whose titles consist of random gobbledygook.

> It seems to me MSE policy is to start the title of a question, as often as possible, with an upper case letter. Is it so?

I'd much rather see titles begin with an uppercase letter whether or not it's a complete  sentence  or ends with a period. All-lowercase titles look lazy. Title case makes perfect sense in principle, but  *on the Internet* I find sentence-case titles easier to look at, especially when long.  I saw enough of Twelve  Amazing Tricks To  Present Page Titles In Most Trashy Way Possible.

Also,   compare with arXiv (below). Sure, arXiv is not a Q&A site, but the comparison makes sense because in both places we have  titles ordered in a long list on a page, with somewhat similar page layout.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you nice and prompt answer! +1! Yes I meant **title**, not *text*. I edited. Sorry for these typos... (Thanks for the edit...)