# Why MSE does not support display mode using "\[...\ ]" and the "\diag"

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

In $\LaTeX$, it is not recommended using

```
$$...  $$
```

for display mode formulas, and

```
\[...\]
```

is more recommended. But it seems the latter is not supported on MSE.
MSE supports

```
\begin{equation*} 
... 
\end{equation*}
```

, but this is akward for typing. Why `\[...\]` is not supported?

And I also found `\diag`, which gives diag in roman font in maths formulas is neither supported.

Comment: As far as I know `\diag` is not supported in LaTeX either: [Inline Notation for the Diagonal of a Matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/621108). (Unless you load some package defining this command.) On [math.se] you can use `$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$` and after that you can use `\diag`. For example, it was defined this way in this question: [Connecting an almost idempotent complex matrix to a diagonal 1-0 matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1168565)

Comment: BTW `$$` is disallowed in the titles: [Using block (displayed) equations in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16946). But from your post it seems that one can bypass this by `\[` and `\]`. This was also pointed out here: [Circumventing displayed equation ban in titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19067).

Comment: A related question on [meta.se]: [What delimiters work for MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375900)

Comment: The [original revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/36193/1) of this questions shows that `\[...\]` behaves differently in the body and in the title. 10k+ users can see this also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845862) (link to a deleted question on the main where I tested the same thing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is meant for testing purposes. (Feel free to edit it if you want to try something related to the issue at hand.)

`\[ x^2+y^2=z^2 \]` - this works neither in the preview nor in the final post.

[ x^2+y^2=z^2 ]

`\\[ x^2+y^2=z^2 \\]` - this works both in the preview and in the posted answer.

\[ x^2+y^2=z^2 \]

As mentioned in the question `$$ x^2+y^2=z^2 $$` works, too.

$$ x^2+y^2=z^2 $$

---

If I include `$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$`, then I can use things like `$\diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)$.`$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$ Here is an example: $\diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)$.

The scope of \newcommand is now restricted to the post (or the comment) where the definition is used - this behavior used to be different, but this was [changed in 2019](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29621).

Comment: ...I can't believe I'm only now learning that `\\[...\\]` works. Inspecting the website for MathJax settings shows that `\\\\(...\\\\)` should also work for inline maths: \\\\(a + b = c\\\\). I get it to work in the preview, have not tried in an answer

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18714/7798).  Note that the MathJax configuration used on StackExchange sites over-escapes the inline delimiters, meaning you need to use quadruple backslashes for them.

Comment: Better yet, see my answer [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5665/38515).  I knew I had answered it before.