# How are **bold** and *italics* presented in comments?

Tags: support, comment, markdown, formatting

I have tried using $<b>bold</b>$ and $<i>italics</i>$ with and without the dollar signs and neither seems to work in **comments**. Although that is what I have seen trying to look underneath comments which use them.
I have searched here using "bold comments" and a few variants but found no answers.

Is it possible that $<b>bold</b>$ in comments is not rendering correctly in my browser, Firefox?

Comment: Use Markdown syntax, `**bold**` **bold**, and `*italics*` *italics*.

Comment: Here is what I get when I use <b>bold</b> in a comment.

Comment: Don't use HTML tags. Use Markdown syntax.

Comment: I thought I had tried that. **bold**  I guess I overlooked the obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Markdown help - comment formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) you can read that

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.
>
> ```
> _italic_ and **bold** text,
> inline `code in backticks`,
> and [basic links](http://example.com).
> ```

And also `*italics*` works for *italics*.

In the linked help you can find more details also about shorthand links and [comment-replies](/questions/tagged/comment-replies). (I have only copied the part releveant to your question about bold and italics.)

You can find even more details in the section of FAQ about comments: [How can I format and link in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)

Again, I will quote here only part relevant to bold and italics:

> Comments can be [formatted with a subset of Markdown](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/): **bold** (`**bold**`), *italic* (`_italic_` or `*italic*`), ***bold italic*** (`***bold italic***` or `___bold italic___`) and `code` (`` `code` ``) are allowed. It is not generally possible to insert line breaks in comments, though some [hacky workarounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/72773#comment236011_72773) exist.

See the comments just below this post where the above syntax is tested.

Comment: Test of the stuff mentioned above in a comment:
_italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `code in backticks`,
and [basic links](http://example.com).
And also `*italics*` works for italics.

Comment: Test of *italics* using stars.

Comment: Right, in the above comment I wrote italics instead of *italics* by mistake. (But, as you probably tried yourself, `*italics*` indeed works.)

Comment: Comments can be [formatted with a subset of Markdown](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/): **bold** (`**bold**`), *italic* (`_italic_` or `*italic*`), ***bold italic*** (`***bold italic***` or `___bold italic___`) and `code` (`\`code\``) are allowed.

Comment: Now that that's settled why does't <text>**bold**</text> work in titles? Or should I look that up under Markdown help - title formatting?  :-)

Comment: @StephenMeskin Meta.SE: [Can we get markdown support in Question's `title` field?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237125) (Some people use MathJax to achieve bold/italics in the title - but this is incorrect use of MathJax; for more details see: [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687).)

Comment: Regular asterisk: * | Bold asterisk: **\*** | Side by side comparison: * **\*** | To get a bold asterisk (**\***), escape the asterisk: `**\***` | So now the question is, how do I get a bold italicized asterisk?!?