# MathJax on simple numbers, the HNQ and a game of 21

Tags: discussion, mathjax, titles

> In question titles, should "simple numbers" – those numbers that stand on their own and which do not require any $\TeX$ symbols to express cleanly – be put into MathJax anyway? Examples include 21 and 0.5.

On 1 March 2019 I answered a question in one of my pet topics: [Is there any other number that has similar properties as $21$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131137/357390) The question got onto HNQ, and I edited the question's title twice in keeping with my intention to have no MathJax formatting around 21.

I was then suspended for a week, and I find the suspension silly.

After the end of said suspension I had a look at the meta questions and found [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16969), which explains how questions with MathJax in their titles are excluded from HNQ and illustrates a possible consequence – something I had figured out by myself very early on. It says

> I think this aspect [MathJax in title excludes a question from HNQ] should be considered when editing questions that can be useful to a broader audience, especially when the benefit of markup is purely cosmetic.

The reason given for my suspension was that I was promoting my answers by making irrelevant edits to the title to remove the MathJax. But I disagree with that reason. Before any edits, the 21 question's title did not have any MathJax. 21 versus $21$ is a purely cosmetic change, and I believed in good faith that the question would be useful more generally, so I hold that I was working to improve the formatting with my edits relevantly, and that *adding* MathJax here is superfluous.

---

My convention is to not put MathJax around simple numbers. I remember that MathWorld follows a similar practice, and I have two reasons for adhering to it:

- The MathJax fonts are different from the fonts used to render normal text, so looks slightly unnatural if it's a simple number that is under the formatting. Compare "42 centimetres" against "$42$ centimetres".
- Most of my answers are typed on the Android app, so I can answer on the go and exercise my brain (my mid-term tests at the National University of Singapore in mathematics and computer science were coming up at the time of my suspension). The $ and \ characters require multiple touches, so in the interests of time I avoid them if doing so does not affect the quality of the formatting.

Comment: "so in the interests of time I avoid them" You don't want to use a second to put MathJax and yet you spent more than a second editing the question to remove the MathJax.

Comment: "so looks slightly unnatural if it's a simple number"  From your answer: "which only holds for $n\le 21$. 21 is the solution"  Doesn't the second 21 look slightly unnatural?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche On your first comment: I believe that the MathJax there was _unnecessary_. (It was Asaf Karagila, not me, who introduced it in the title.) On your second comment: the second 21 doesn't look unnatural to me at all.

Comment: You got suspended for a week, for editing a title twice?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, even though I made those edits in good faith, as explained in the body.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Gerry, that's *quite* an oversimplification. (And since we do not discuss suspensions publicly, that is all I can say for now.)

Comment: Also, Parcly, you *knew* that MathJax excludes questions from HNQ before the end of your suspension. And I know that, because even before I was a moderator you already argued with me about something similar in the comments of some question. I know that you want to write your own narrative in a positive light, but at least try to make it honest.

Comment: Case in point for my last remark, https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2631135/2 (that alone should have had you suspended *back then*, actively sabotaging the site for your own gain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job of $\rm\LaTeX$ is to separate the mathematics from the text. This makes it easier to immediately grasp and understand which part of the text is the mathematical part.

The text, however, includes the title.

> The intersection of 2 sets is empty

If almost fine, because 2 is not there in a "mathematical capacity". (In general single digit numbers should be spelled out in these situation.)

In contrast,

> How many 3 x 3 matrices are there over the field with 2 elements?

Should be in $\rm\LaTeX$, because $3\times 3$ stands out more, and in this case I would even consider putting the 2 in $\rm\LaTeX$ (or even replacing the whole phrase with $\Bbb F_2$ or $\Bbb{Z/2Z}$).

Doing these kind of thing is *not* a silly formatting meant to take your answer off the HNQ, it is meant to make the question more readable in a quicker way.

This is exactly the same reason why you won't use $\varepsilon$ to denote a natural number in analysis, or use $\pi$ to denote a finite set of algebraic numbers in number theory. You could argue that those are just letters and that is justified, and you'd be right. But we learn to take context-hints from the notation and text we read. Which is why mathematical parts of a question ***including the title*** should be written in $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: (I brought up the 3 x 3 thing, because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2485531/revisions) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2631135/revisions), by the way. Just to put some light on your prior behavior...)

Comment: Sure, I understand, but "mathematical capacity" is quite subjective. Perhaps you should give guidelines in an easily accessible place for future reference (like the "guidelines on good use of $\LaTeX$ in titles" question I linked in my question's body). I will accept your answer nevertheless.

Comment: As an aside, I note that internally you use `\Bbb` instead of `\mathbb` for blackboard bold. I was told off once by Did when I was still using `\Bbb`, on the grounds that that is deprecated, and now use `\mathbb`. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: In my actual $\rm\LaTeX$ I never use `\Bbb`, here it doesn't matter since they are synonyms (unlike `\rm` and `\mathrm`).

Comment: Am I all good now, fresh out of understanding the need to delineate the maths in questions and answers?