# If I vote to close a question because of no effort shown, is the OP given a reason before closing? Why not?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, closing

Sorry for the long title.  I have noticed that whenever I have flagged a question because it was a duplicate, a comment appeared immediately informing everyone that the question was a probable duplicate.  I recently crossed the 3K bar and it seems I have the ability to vote to close questions.  One of the reasons I can choose is relatively new (I found a reference to it dated September 16, 2013, and I don't think it's much older):

"This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

If I vote to close a question for this reason, does this paragraph immediately appear as a comment below the question (similar for flags for duplicate questions)?  If not, would it be possible to change the system so that it does?  That would give the OP a chance to improve his/her question before it gets closed.

I am not a computer person, so I have no idea how this would be done, but the fact that something similar happens with flags for duplicate questions suggests that it is possible.

I know many people write friendly comments such as "Hello, welcome to MSE!  Please tell us what you've tried, and check [this link] for advice on how to write a good question" and so forth, but so many bad, "Do my homework for me" questions appear on MSE that it would take a long time to provide this comment on every such question that one sees.  Maybe a lot of inexperienced users are unfamiliar with the etiquette here, but I think a lot of users really do want us to do their homework for them.  If someone posts a mere PSQ, I cannot tell which kind of user it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a feature request on Meta Stack Overflow:

[Use inbox notification for close/open related activities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191423/use-inbox-notification-for-close-open-related-activities)

The application of it on MSE would be to give another, seemingly decisive, reason to nuke all "what have you tried" comments that discuss nothing except the level of effort : the OP already got the message, quietly, impersonally, and without any comment drama.

There is no indication that SE will implement the feature.

Comment: Stackoverflow automatically blocks "what have you tried" and strings similar to that as comments.  This was noted in earlier meta.MSE conversation, but adding it here for redundancy.

Comment: So do it automatically with one click! (if feature is added).  It would clean up the comments under questions considerably.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand the concept of the OP "deserving" anything, whether it is answers or "help" or what-have-you-tried comments.  The OP posts a question hoping it will interest people here enough to get some useful answer.  This is a marketing problem for the OP.  If they solve it, great.  If they are not able to make the question interesting enough, bad luck.  No problem and no "deserves".

Comment: @zyx, are you one of those pure free market folks? "What do you mean it's bad? I managed to sell it!"

Comment: @dfeuer, I am emphatically not a fan of the markets or of marketing.  I just find it absurd to overlay moral concepts onto disposable postings on a free internet site.  SE can junk whatever they (don't) want, or take down the site at any time, for all that we users know.  It is a pastime that happens to generate useful long term content, and that's good, but I am not here to help anyone or teach anybody anything and I think it would be extremely beneficial (and would actually maximize the amount of effective helping and teaching that occurs on MSE) if similar attitudes were the social norm.

Comment: Having said that, it is true that I am of the techno-anarchist stripe as regards opinion on what is good for the site.  **Machine readable metadata** is far more important than comment drama and closings.

Comment: @zyx, some people *are* here in part because we like helping and teaching. I agree, however, that it could be nice to have a more standardized way to inform new users of site standards.

Comment: @dfeuer, clearly that is the (self-perceived) motivation for some.  But note the suggestion about what would maximize helping and teaching, for those who would like to accomplish that.

Comment: @Stefan: I consider it elementary courtesy, something that everyone deserves.

Comment: @zyx: I suppose that I see it as half a crumb being better than no bread.

Comment: @zyx : maybe I shouldn't have used the word "deserves".  If an OP is unwilling to take the time to put some thought into a question and write what they have attempted, I am not going spend time composing an answer or giving them an etiquette lesson.

Comment: @zyx : if close-voting for all well formed mathematical questions is instrinsically discourteous, then why is there a reason to close that pretty explicitly gives lack of effort as a reason to close questions ("... which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it ...").  The fact that this reason to close exists indicates that many disagree with you about this, or at least some people who run the show here.

Comment: @zyx : If an OP's question does get closed, then they do get an explanation of why it was closed, which ought to help the OP ask better questions in the future.  Unfortunately, by the time the question is closed, the problem has probably been answered.  It would be nice if OP's were alerted automatically of votes to close with reasons, at least in the comments, they way they are with duplicate questions, so they find out sooner.

Comment: @zyx : I don't understand your comment about machine readable metadata.

Comment: @StefanSmith, to be clear, I fully support the feature-request and was considering making it myself on Meta Stack Overflow before you posted the question.  As for the existence of the "low effort" close vote reason, it is the result of popular support among (newer) meta users for some way of controlling basic homework postings, but my previously posted views on that it were that it is ineffective (as is now obvious from the continuing loud complaints after months of closings) and that homework is quite literally a scapegoat, for phenomena related to growth in the size of the user population.

Comment: @zyx : regarding your "marketing problem" analogy: people who post "Do my homework for me" PSQ's here don't seem to have much of a marketing problem.  Their questions are usually answered completely, correctly, and almost immediately, by users who I assume really want the points.  I don't think anyone learns much from these answers.

Comment: @StefanSmith, my opinion is that a less emotional (or less "prior-heavy", in the Bayesian sense) examination of the situation would show that problem-only homework postings are fine ethically, and a benefit for the site.  The only problem in them from my perspective is the lack of specificity in titles and tags, that would help separate out the problems that are more interesting to read or answer.

Comment: @Stefan: I answer such questions because I think that they deserve answers, and I feel strongly enough that I have often answered them in comments after they were closed. My answers are usually hints, albeit sometimes quite extensive, just as they are with most low-level questions.

Comment: @zyx, we disagree with on the ethics of the matter. I think the PSQ homework issue is a problem apart from its part in the growth-related problems. I know that Brian M. Scott will forever disagree with me on this.

Comment: @dfeuer, the ethical aspect was never dissected in any detail on meta, so we are left with a lot of unreflective "OMG cheating!" as the modal opinion around here.  I do not believe it withstands analysis.  Ethical problems are present, but in the conduct of the instructors and institutions that (among many other troubles) use outsource-able evaluation tools while operating as a provider of credentials.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I highly approve of hints in favor of complete answers.  Unfortunately complete answers seem to get accepted more by OP's and often even outvoted by MSE users.  Regarding your comment about elementary courtesy, I'm not sure.  Maybe the OP is a Bob, a lazy slob who wants me to do his homework for him.  Then I don't think I have to do go out of my way to be nice to him and suggest how to ask a good question, etc., which takes time....

Comment: @dfeuer: And I have considerable evidence that a great many posters of PSQs *will* do some work if pushed in the right direction.

Comment: @Stefan: I prefer to give the OP the benefit of the doubt. And I’ve had a rather substantial number of hints accepted even when there were competing complete (or more complete) answers.

Comment: ...Maybe the OP is Mary, a hard worker who just doesn't know the etiquette here and thinks just asking a question is fine.  I would be willing to give Mary a little time suggesting how to improve her question (I will avoid the word "deserves").  I can't always tell Bob from Mary from reading their questions.  That's the point of my question.  Another possibility would be to have a button we could click that produced a boilerplate comment, such as people often write, welcoming the OP to MSE, suggesting they say what they've tried, giving a link to a guide on writing good questions, etc.

Comment: @Stefan: I don’t feel any need to distinguish Bob from Mary on reading the question. What’s important is the question, and after that the OP’s response, if any, to answers and comments.

Comment: **"Machine readable metadata"** meant that precise tags, and full use of informative titles, and references and keywords that make the Related Questions list more accurate, and upvotes (which massively outnumber downvotes and are used more consistently), are together much more effective in helping identify the superior content that one wants to read, than attempts to block what some people deem to be inferior based on style more than mathematical content. Even downvotes are a waste of time as far as I can tell, due to the extreme variance in the frequency of use, and inconsistency of meaning.

Comment: (It follows that another, constructive but underutilized, way to increase the differentiation of interesting postings from the rest is: to not volunteer any improvement of titles, tags, references, clarifications of question, etc for the questions you don't want to promote, and do provide those things, along with upvotes, for the questions you do want to get more visibility.)

Comment: @zyx, removing inappropriate tags is *always* a good thing, perhaps *especially* on bad questions. I never want to read a bad question about number theory, but I even more don't want to read a bad question about number theory when I'm looking for info on linear algebra.

Comment: @dfeuer, sure, and most people (myself included) probably don't think twice about which type of question it is when correcting ridiculous tags.  But for a typical question there are usually several significant improvements that can be made, and concentrating those on the questions one wants to promote is similar to upvoting, but more effective in distinguishing them (as far as I can see from reading the site), simply because it is somewhat uncommon for maximum use to be made of the tags and title space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I admit I don't have any hard data on how many good hints are upvoted and accepted as opposed to complete answers to PSQ's, so I will try to avoid words like "most" when discussing these issues.  But I think complete answers are upvoted way more than they should be and and good hints are upvoted way less than they should be.  I think that for most elementary questions, the OP will learn more from seeing a good hint than from having a complete solution handed to him/her.

Comment: @zyx : from what you have written, it sounds like if I don't like seeing PSQ's and "Do my homework for me" type questions posted on MSE, I should _not_ upvote "what have your tried" type comments or make such comments myself.  Is that correct?

Comment: If you don't like seeing a category of questions that is objectively identifiable, there is a solution that actually works based on **machine readable metadata**: tag them as [problem-only-question] and set them to Ignore.  Alternatives involve a lot of negative drama, with WHYT'ers asking aggressive (and phony) questions to which they don't intend to read or use the answer, and the answer not usable by anyone else if is given; developing a mentality of restricting others' use of the site; and all the wonderful side effects that come with that. @StefanSmith

Comment: @zyx: I am not sure that it is only "newer" users who supported the close reason.  Also, even *ignoring* the PSQ issue, I think that the "no context" close reason is better than the previous "this is homework" reason. The newer one is more constructive, avoids the red-herring homework issue entirely, and gives the asker better guidance on how to improve the question.

Comment: Did I write "only" newer users, or newer users? There was a shift in active meta users. Some relatively liberal older users who were active on meta (e.g., JDH, Matt E) stopped posting, another was suspended (Bill) during all the closing discussions, newer and more aggressively restriction-oriented users appeared and became increasingly vocal (we both know who several of them are).  There is ongoing discussion as to whether the "context" closing pressure is making questions better or worse (here, for example: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/ ). @CarlMummert

Answer (score 8):

> If I vote to close a question for this reason, does this paragraph immediately appear as a comment below the question (similar for flags for duplicate questions)?

No, unless you use a "custom" close reason, in which case it is inserted as a comment automatically.

> If not, would it be possible to change the system so that it does?

This leads to a broader issue with close votes. Because the OP is not given any notification otherwise, when you vote to close,
$$
{\large \mbox{It is polite to leave a comment explaining the close votes}}$$

This is up to each voter, of course. It is not a formal rule, but a polite practice. You can always just copy the close reason from the dialog box and post it as a comment.   There is also a [list of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) for copying.

Of course, if there is already a good comment, or if the the issue has been explained to the OP before (e.g. spam), there is no need to leave a comment in *every* case.