# Question on users that don't accept answers.

Tags: discussion, comment, accepted-answer

I've  seen on several occasion that it is not considered wrong to ask a user if he/she could please accept an answer. For instance it is discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6984/145141). My question is slightly though significantly different.
It has happened to me, more than once that I see a  (quite interesting)  question to which I know the/an answer. Out of curiosity I click on the OP's name to view his/her profile first. I then see that this user rarely accepts any answers, even if they completely solve his/her question. So I would like to know how well received an action like this would be: place a comment that says something like:

> "Though I think I can be of assistance to you here, I've noticed that you rarely accept any answers and I therefore choose not to answer your question, because I'd rather help someone that is more likely to express his/her appreciation."

**Edit:** My idea was that comments like this could encourage a user to change his/her accepting habbits. I've read in one of the links by Gerry Myerson that accept marks are not a *significant issue*. I agree with that as far as you consider the mechanics of the site or the wellbeing of someone who answers (no one will die if their answer isn't accepted). But for me it's more like a common courtesy thing. If I know someone is not going to bother to show his/her gratitude, I just don't feel like answering. Anyway, that just my way of looking at  it. I was just curious how other feel about this.

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/people-who-do-not-accept-answers-suggestion-for-dealing-with-this

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15082/users-who-do-not-accept-answers

Comment: IMHO, this is rude.

Comment: Suggesting that they accept is reasonable, adding the implied middle finger seems unnecessary and designed to taunt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internet comments undergo  mysterious transformations as they travel from one screen to another.  There is what your comment may look  like on the other user's screen:

> - **I** am boycotting **you** until **you** meet **my** demand. Because **I'd rather** [an irrelevant statement of the commenter's personal preferences]

It's too personal, and not in a pleasant way. If a comment can't be personal in a pleasant way, it should be impersonal.  There is already a [template of such a comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/147263). But now that I look at it, it feels too long for such a simple matter, with *two* links in it.  Here's a shorter option  which would fit the scenario you describe:

> Users who [accept good answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to their past questions are more likely to have their future questions answered.

This would be best posted on a question that sat without any activity for a while. The comment links to a section of  Help Center, which presents information in nicely laid out, easily linkable chunks. (Most of templated comments were written before Help Center existed.)

Comment: Of course there's a fly in the soup on that page. It opens with "The first thing you should do when someone answers your question is vote on it". I disagree: the first thing should be to read the answer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried come up with a comment as polite as possible, but you are right to say that a written text is better received if it impersonal.

Comment: I changed the link to point to another page of Help Center.

Comment: **I** am boycotting **you** until **you** meet my demands. Because **I'd rather** binge watch Game of Thrones than sitting through lectures in differential geometry.

Comment: I wrote the comment from the original question. Let me know how it showed up on your screen.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It showed up as a compliment to Ted Shifrin.