# Is it bad form to ask the OP to officially accept your answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepted-answer

There are quite a few times that this has happened - the OP has clearly been satisfied with my answer (eg by saying thanks for the help) and has found it useful, but presumably doesn't know how the site works really, and has not accepted my answer. Is it then bad form to remind them to accept, or to tell them to accept, or is that just a risk we take when answering questions?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers

Comment: dammit i did a search and didn't find anything! is that why the downvote? also clearly it is a good thing to accept, but what about reminding the OP?

Comment: There is definitely also a duplicate for that, but I can't find it now.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/is-it-wrong-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-an-answer seems closer