# Symbols in use on this site?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I need to use certain symbols when asking someone to assist with a problem.
Is there a list I can go to or quick method of using them, please?
I am new to this site btw.

I will delete this question as soon as possible so it doesn't get in the way of other people's questions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't know symbols names or you don't know symbols?

Comment: Like they used to say on *G.I. Joe*, knowing is half the battle. If you know what the symbol is called, then you can look it up on your favorite search engine, e.g., the circled plus sign $\oplus$, or the Fraktur P $\mathfrak P$.

Comment: I bookmarked all the links, thank you.

Comment: A few links related to writing *mathematical expressions* on this site can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome to Math SE!

Have a look at [*how to format mathematics*](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE.

Here is a very cool little tool called [*Detexify LaTeX*](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) where you can draw the symbol you are looking for and the system will tell you what the TeX command is.

Finally, I suggest that you bookmark this very useful [*MathJax tutorial*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
as a quick reference for future posts.

---

**Edit**

Using *Wolfram*, another useful tool is `TeXForm[expr]` which converts a Wolfram input into TeX. It is possible to go from one language to the other with either `ToExpression["input",TeXForm]`or `TeXForm[expr]` to convert documents.

(See [Generating and Importing TeX](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneratingAndImportingTeX.html))

Comment: Thanks for your patience and assistance. sorry to trouble you. :D

Comment: Wil delete in a minute or so.

Comment: @bobh No problem and don't be sorry for needing help. If that answer helped you, please click the green check next to it to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have done that, and am now deleting this post. thx for your time. I bookmarked the pages etc.  :D  Have a good day.

Comment: @bobh It is recommended that you avoid deleting questions that received answers since this content may be useful to other users in the future, thanks understanding.

Comment: OK I will leave it there.Bye

Comment: I think quite a few programming languages do that, i know sage does with `latex(expr)` to turn maths into latex,

Answer (score 8):

The [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) is also an excellent reference for symbols and typesetting.

Comment: Great ressource, thank you for that!