# MathJax info; can anyone re-direct me to the info page on this site?

Tags: support, mathjax

I have misplaced my links to the MathJax instructions and can't see the link that used to be here. I especially need to remind myself of the codes for combinations.
Help?

Comment: Thanks; that will work well.

Comment: Do you mean [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619)? To prevent losing it again you can go to that page and click the star in the left margin, just under the vote count of the post. Clicking that star turns it yellow. After that you can retrieve the page from [the favorites tab of your profile page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/412473/victoria?tab=favorites). Observe that the profile pages for Meta.Math.SE and Math.SE are separate. If you don't want to keep that in your list of favorites, then you can just click the star again, turning it back to grey.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean but "MathJax instructions". But quite often links to relevant information on some topic can be found in the corresponding tag-info on meta,
 in this case for [the mathjax tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info). And perhaps also some of the links in [this comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4928#4928) might be what you are looking for.