# Requesting for like or best answer

Tags: discussion, comment, badges, accepted-answer

I have received "polite" requests on 2 questions to accept the posted answer as best by the answerer claiming it will give them a badge. Is it OK, tolerated or objectionable practice?

Comment: What does "like" in the title refer to? I really can't parse that in meaningful English. "Request to accept answers" would have been a clearer title.

Comment: I think it's totally ok to give them their "like'' I mean it doesn't affect you or me, it's just like a game and the more badges you have the better.

Comment: @AlexM.I presume that the OP refers to an upvote as "like".

Answer (score 15):

It depends.

I've seen some occasions where a user posts a 'thank you, this helped' comment under my answer. If it's a user who is new to the site, and hasn't accepted any answers yet, I usually reply with something like:

> Since you're new to the site, I'd like to remind you that you can [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it helped you. But you can also wait until a better answer comes along.

That's just teaching a new user the basic functionalities of this site, in a way that leaves them with a choice not to accept (yet).

**However**, seeing that you accept an answer [more than half of the times you ask a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/431608/xi-jinping?tab=questions), it's rather inappropriate in your case. You can [flag those comments as not constructive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/295232); comments are meant to [request clarification or add minor and transient information](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). See also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199008/295232) by one of the Stack Overflow employees.

P.S. accepting an answer doesn't give them badges (well, most of the times). It's just the +15 reputation that they're probably after.

Comment: I will add that there is also [a comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945) related to accepting answers.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it awards badges, why would anyone vote or accept on that basis?

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: I don't care about 15 points, but I do care about knowing that the OP considers the problem solved, and also showing one's gratitude makes a difference to me. Upvoting and accepting is the way to say "thanks" to an answerer, and accepting shows that the case is closed.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta then you're probably the exception to the rule. I *agree* that a 'proper' user of Stack Exchange *should* accept an answer that is satisfactory to him/her, and whenever I have a question, I tend to do so. However, reminding established users of this, who by their history seem to know how to accept an answer, is pointless and (IMHO) inappropriate.

Comment: "an answer doesn't give them badges (well, most of the times)" I do not, in any way, want to say these comments are acceptable, but it is quite annoying to *not* get a silver badge (Enlightened) just because the OP leaves a comment "Thanks!" instead of accepting the answer. (I do not really care much about badges, but it is sort of satisfying to get one)