# List of popular links in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review

Recently I have started participating in the review queues on the main site more often, and frequently I find myself wanting to link new people to places, such as [the Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), '[How to ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960)', '[How to Choose a Good Title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)', '[How to Tag a Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9961)', and even just the [General Help Centre](https://math.stackexchange.com/help)

Each time I do, I have to go and find the relevant page to retrieve the link for myself. Maybe a good feature to add would be to have a list of these popular links on the right hand side, while you are in the [First Posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) review queue in particular, and maybe other queues too.

Comment: It's not really the same thing, but there is [List of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925).

Comment: For the help center there is a dedicated shortcut `[help]` yielding [help] there are also `[help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior], [tour]` for  [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior], [tour] (note the links are actually to distinct pages) and a few others https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you, hadn't come across that before

Comment: @quid Thanks, those might come in handy some time. Maybe it's worth having these listed next to review in question, for people who don't know them (or forget them as I'm prone to do!)