# Could we have a link to the OP's ping like [edit]?

Tags: feature-request, users

Here's an idea:

> Please could we have a link option in the comments, like `[edit]`, that gets replaced by the asker's tag (*e.g.*, `[OP]` in the comments would be replaced by @Shaun here)?

This would make things easier; in particular, it would make [comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925/104041) more personal.

What d'you think?

Comment: Similar feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Magic link for OP (original poster)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288787).

Comment: There is [a tag on Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-links) called "magic-links".  It is infrequent, even rare, that new magic links are implemented.  The last one I spotted with "status-completed" is from August, 2016.  Such feature requests are often neither approved nor declined, even when voting on Meta indicates a healthy interest in the proposed feature.