# Is there any way to have comment templates whenever we are typing comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment, user-scripts

We already have a comment template thread but oftentimes it takes a long time to open meta, go to the question, wait for the page to load, scroll down to the correct comment and copy it, especially if one's internet is slow. Is there any way we could have an opt-in method for a side-panel to open up when typing a comment with the common comment templates straight from that answer. If not, could we have a user-script to do the same job?

Comment: If somebody has enough time to try it out, perhaps this userscript is worth checking out: [QuickComment: comment shortcuts to cut down on tedium](https://stackapps.com/q/4796). (And it's possible that you might find some other similar tools on Stack Apps.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak for example, I use `htagq` → Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have always used [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) with great pleasure. It sounds like it would exactly fit your wishes.

It is completely configurable using a text editor, using which you can easily include your favourites from the [list of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates).

---

As an aside, to save you time copy-pasting in general, you could look into using a clipboard history like [ClipX](https://bluemars.org/clipx/). It has become an indispensable "quality of life" tool for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, text replacement shortcuts are a built-in feature. Its less capable than the other options, but requires no installation and should Just Work in every browser (in fact, system-wide, which might be too much...)

You can find this option by opening `System Preferences > Keyboard`, and then the `Text` submenu. You should see this window (or something similar if you're on a newer OS):

[image]

The `+/-` in the bottom left lets you add/delete items in the list. For instance, typing `msehow`(apparently its not case-sensitive) and hitting space turns it into the following text that I just made up:

> Hi there, your question as currently phrased is likely to attract close votes and downvotes. To avoid this and also to get the best answers suited to your understanding, I suggest checking [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/)