# Button for "First Posts" MathJax-based review

Tags: feature-request, review, new-users

When I review "First Posts" questions, a lot of reviews consist of pointing out new users on using MathJax by leaving a comment. Can't we establish a button which automatically creates a comment to the question/answer with a polite standard text pointing out to the [MathJaX tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)? I know users (should) see this already when they are asking their first question, but it seems like they overlook it sometimes or it is something different when they are pointed out by an actual user.

Comment: Actually, when I review "first posts" (questions), I am most concerned about what might look like a bare problem statement question, with no context.  Should I ask for a button, which places an automatic comment referring them to "How to ask a good Question"? If all you want to comment on in a very low quality question, to mention only "here is where you can learn overnight how to use mathjax", it ain't gonna happen that quickly.  I suggest we focus on content, and less on form, when a user is posting their very first questions or answers.

Comment: Yes, we want users to be aware of the tutorial, and tend to expect them to learn basic mathjax, but I think it is unreasonable to chastise them if they don't use it on there first, second, or even third posts.  Some users learn just as much from the edits others make of their posts.  But at some point beyond "new user", it is absolutely okay to call out both askers, and answerers, who who don't use mathjax.  In fact there is a user now that has over 16 K in rep, but refuses to use mathjax.  I have never upvoted their answers.

Comment: This older question seems a bit similar: [Is there any way to have comment templates whenever we are typing comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30364)