# Double struck 1 in Mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax, font, typesetting

I want to type the  symbol in Mathjax (physics.stackexchange) without having to copy the Ascii character. I found
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204998/double-struck-zero-and-one which mentioned

```
 \mathbbm{1}
 \mathds{1}
 \mathbb{1}
```

The first two options don't work and the last option looks like a regular 1. Since it's on stackexchange I can't import modules as far as I know.

Comment: `$\mathbb{1}$` seems to do the job:  $\mathbb{1}$.  That being said, MathJax is not TeX, and does not support all of the features that a real TeX or LaTeX implementation supports.

Comment: @XanderHenderson in a previous meta post [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31832/how-can-i-typeset-blackboard-bold-numbers/31834#31834) (possible dupe?) I found out that this is browser/math renderer dependent. It works on Macs and iOS devices

Comment: @CalvinKhor Good to know.  It works for me.  That being said, I'll reiterate my previous comment:  MathJax is not TeX. :\

Comment: Indeed, how I wish TeX allowed me to mathbb my 1s without weird packages

Comment: @CalvinKhor  The dsfont package isn't that big a deal.  I wanted a doublestruck / blackboard bold $i$ for my thesis, and had to engage in all kinds of hackery to get that to work.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon as in the linked post you can also memorise x1D7D9 to write `\unicode{x1D7D9}`$\unicode{x1D7D9}$ which can be wrapped in a newcommand

Comment: @CalvinKhor I see! Will use that in the future.

Comment: I find that `$\mathbb{1}$` works only if I change the Math Renderer to MathML. (Firefox 86.0.1 on Windows 7.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nearly a dupe but seeing how no one voted to close maybe I can try to summarise the information better than the exploratory post [there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31832/how-can-i-typeset-blackboard-bold-numbers/31834#31834). AFAIK the current options are

| Description | Input | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Copy paste the Unicode symbol | `$$` | $$ |
| The naive `\mathbb1` (not reccomended: [only works with some setups](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/792) e.g. HTML-CSS renderer on machines with the STIX fonts installed) | `$\mathbb1$` or `$\Bbb1$` | $\mathbb1$ or $\Bbb1$ |
| Memorise the hexadecimal number that encodes , x1D7D9 (the `D`s are case insensitive) | `$\unicode{x1D7D9}$` | $\unicode{x1d7d9}$ |
| Place one of the above in a `\newcommand` | `$\newcommand{\one}{\unicode{x1d7d9}}$`, then `$\one$` | $\newcommand{\one}{\unicode{x1d7d9}}\one$ |

A possible alternative to using `\newcommand` would be to use some sort of clipboard feature. (This may involve installing  software.) For instance Macs come with a system wide text replacement feature built-in; so one can make something like `mseone` automatically turn into `\unicode{x1d7d9}`; some details are in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33153/80734).

The following 'substitutes' are easier to use:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `$\mathbf1$`or `$\bf1$` | $\mathbf1$ or $\bf1$ |
| `$\pmb1$` or `$1\!\!1$` | $\pmb1$ or $1\!\!1$ |
| `$1\!\rm l$` (variant of the above) | $1\!\rm l$ |

- One can get creative e.g. `\pmb` can be iterated: $\pmb{\pmb{\pmb{\pmb{1}}}}$ but if you're going to do something hard, you might as well use `\unicode{x1D7d9}`.
- Since $1+2=3$ and `x1D7D9+2=x1D7DB`, the code `$\unicode{x1D7DB}$` outputs $\unicode{x1D7DB}$.
- Having `\mathbb1` be equivalent to the Unicode input `\unicode{x1d7d9}` is a [planned feature](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/792) of Mathjax v3, but (IIRC) at the time of writing Mathematics SE does not have plans to use Mathjax v3.
- Perusing a table of characters, here is a non-exhaustive list of other mathematical Unicode symbols that I do not know the equivalent Mathjax code for that nonetheless display well for me in Safari v14.0.3 on my Mac (but some have obvious substitutes):

| Description | Output |
| --- | --- |
| variant integral signs | $∯∰⨕∱∲∳⨋⨍⨎⨏⨖⨗⨘⨙⨚⨛⨜$ |
| variant equality symbols | $≉≋≌≎≏≐≑≒≓≔≕≖≗≘≙≚≛≜≝≞≟≣⊜$ |
| variant binary operators/relations | $⊌⊍⊎⊑⊒⊏⊐⊓⊔⊘⊚⊛⊝⊞⊟⊠⊡⨃⨄⨴⨵⨶⨷⨸⨹⨺⨻$ |
| degree symbol `5°` (distinct from `^\circ`$^\circ$ or `^o`$^o$) | $5°$ |
| greek or lowercase in blackboard-bold | $ℿ⅀ℽ$ |

(not included in the list: `\iiiint`, `\oint` $\iiiint,\oint$, `\cong`, `\simeq`, `\equiv`$\cong,\simeq,\equiv$, `\otimes`, `\oplus`, `\ominus`, `\odot`, `\bigoplus`, `\bigotimes`, `\bigodot` $\otimes,\oplus,\ominus,\odot,\bigoplus ,\bigotimes,\bigodot$.)
Some of them need extra code; consider `⨃_{a\in\Lambda} U_a` vs `⨃\limits_{a\in\Lambda} U_a` $$⨃_{a\in\Lambda} U_a \quad \text{vs}\quad ⨃\limits_{a\in\Lambda} U_a$$

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer! The \mathbb 1 renders like a regular one for me so I guess I'll have to stick to copying the Unicode symbol.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion you don't like memorising x1D7D9? :) I've certainly memorised it after writing this answer... You're welcome

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I just thought of another way: the chief problem is the ability to turn something you type into something that displays as $\unicode{x1d7d9}$. You can achieve this with a dedicated clipboard program that can store snippets of text (like `\unicode{x1d7d9}`) and have them paste this in your text field when you type a keyword. I’ve added this to the answer (but unfortunately I don’t know of specific programs for this outside of a built in feature of Mac OS; ‘there must be an app for that’. Suggestions welcome)