# Should you remind people to upvote questions?

Tags: discussion

Should you remind people to upvote your questions? Is this helpful/necessary? Would this be considered rude or inappropriate? Thank you for your input.

Comment: I  have downvoted your question.  As you are a new user, you might like to know that downvotes on meta do not work the same way as they do on the main site.  On meta, an upvote means (roughly) "I agree with this post" while a downvote means "I disagree with this post."  Personally, I think that asking people to vote on your questions/answers is just plain "thirsty".  Such requests are not, in my opinion, even remotely appropriate.  Hence I have downvoted.

Comment: By the rules of the site, it's not allowed to comment this kind of things _but_ what you could do is, to 'remind' to upvote, on your profile (it's uncommon to see this though, but I think it's harmless)

Comment: Indeed, I agree with the viewpoints expressed here.  But, for me at least, I also frown on answerers who answer a question  asking users for upvotes on their answer.  So in this respect, it's not just about askers not doing so, it also applies to answerers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. You should *not* ask people to vote your posts or accept your answers. That is inappropriate.

I know how it feels like when you're just starting, and it's hard to get more points. But that's why you need to work hard, post good questions and good answers, and you'll get there in time.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with asking people to accept answers; at last for the sake of removing the question from the list of unanswered questions. In addition, I think there's a reason we have [a template for this situation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/537079). Of course, posting this below a question you answered yourself might appear wrong. Beside this, I agree that asking for upvotes is inappropriate.

Comment: I find it to be in bad taste asking for people to accept *your* answer.