# Enforce accurate titles more strictly

Tags: feature-request, titles

The questions I view here have repetitive or inaccurate titles. I think this site as whole would be more useful if people paid more attention to titles. and, I think that can happen if we are more strict about the rules we have regarding it.

Comment: The choir you are preaching to agrees!  Unfortunately there is no question here, and probably no dissenting opinions to discuss. Your next course of action is to tell *the posters* and to sometimes help them choose a better title.  Speaking for myself, I frequently make comments about title improvement and improve titles on my own.

Comment: As for this being a feature request, it *would* be nice if it could be done automatically, it's just that the problem is very hard to solve algorithmically.  Peer review is apparently a faster and more accurate fixer.  But... if you have a lead on some algorithm that might help, it would be a good thing to add.

Comment: It's a problem on many Stack Exchange sites. I once saw a question on [so] titled 'PHP developer' (or something slightly longer) - the author thought they were supposed to put their *job* title there ...

Comment: I will add that there is a comment template in the [List of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925#4931).

Comment: Should the discussion tag be added to this question?