# Improving MathJax experience for beginners

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, comment, new-users

I don't know if this has already been discussed here on the meta, but since most of these 'MathJax Tutorial' have been meant for beginners, wouldn't it make sense if they could comment asking their queries on how to use MathJax.

As of now, you need $50$ Reps to be able to comment, but this often deters others from learning especially those who might have been downvoted for not using MathJax. The only other alternative would be to ask a question with a link to the post, for a small misunderstanding that might have been cleared by the OP himself on his post.

Comment: Where do you propose that they be allowed to comment? They can already comment on their own questions and answers. (Also, this sounds like it is not something that the moderators can change, so would require someone higher-up to do something. and that's a little unlikely)

Comment: Possibly one could ask about MathJax also in chat (there is a [chatroom called MathJax](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13752/mathjax)). Chat can be used [from 20 reputation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) - with a minor advantage that it is not necessary to have 20 reputation points here on [math.se], it can be from another site. (Still, as pointed out in the previous comment, anybody can comment on their own posts.)

Comment: There has been recent discussion here on improving the MathJax experience for beginners. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33103/207316 & https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/207316

Comment: Well yes this could be helpful but there's also this requirement of minimum reputation for protection for math.SE.

Comment: I think that with the new-to-be MathJax tutorial for beginners,  would improve a lot the experience for beginners.