# Overuse of problem-solving

Tags: support, tagging

I noticed that the tag [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) is used frequently by newbies who have just one problem which they need to solve. Will anyone mind if I start deleting these tags from questions which are certainly not related to problem solving? That will result in many edit requests, so I don't want to do this job if it turns out that I'm going to do something wrong.

Comment: No hurry. I think the moderator have the option of deleting the tag without bumping (if that is what the community what) I notice thr same thing too and was  wondering if the tag is really useful.

Comment: Maybe [a comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/8587#8587) for this tag could be created?

Comment: Start following the [tag:set-theory] tag. People keep putting it on questions because "they involve a set".

Comment: We have to solve this problem about the tag [tag:problem-solving].

Comment: What about this? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/33112#33112

Comment: I won't mind if you start deleting the tag, provided you only do it to three or four questions a day. I don't want to see the front page flooded with old questions that have been bumped just for the sake of deleting a tag.

Comment: We should prioritize new Questions which are inappropriately tagged.  Removing a poor tag gives an opportunity to supply a good one.