# Copy-paste welcome message to newbies

Tags: discussion

I suggest that we come up with 'standard' set of welcome message to newbies, as it is a trend I find that questions from newbies are insta downvoted. I think it may be that they are not familiar with the site yet and a push in the right direction.

The standard we keep each other upto on this site is very high (believe it or not), and it may be that new  people don't pick up all the rules and etiquettes in their first few questions. So, I think that we should formulate a standard set of post replies which we send to newbies such that they can understand what specifically is there mistake.

On helpcenter:

Yes, this pretty much contains all the information needed to be a 'good' participant on this site, but it is difficult to make a person read through all of them. Instead of expecting people to read through the help center text carefully ( I don't think most newbies even bother) , we can rather change how we use the site slightly and expect a better outcome.

Comment: Isn't this what the Help Centre is?

Comment: @postmortes Yes in a way that is the answer but I think a bring a point to a person's notice more effectively if it's a real person saying the point instead of an automated message( I mean think of the last time you were installing a program or so and you had to agree to the rules and policies of that program distributor)

Comment: FYR: There's a lot of comment template [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates).

Comment: That is a helpful post.