# "Bookmarks" option below "Home" link or among top-right options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

Often times I find myself visiting the bookmarked post of "meta". So:

1. Open meta in new tab.
2. Click on the profile.
3. Click on "Bookmarks".

And now I select the one required.

This, despite repeating a lot of times doesn't get faster and seems too much bother too when just to post a "Welcome comment" or any other comments [from here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates); or consulting [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for Mathjax help, I have repeat it over.

Apart from that, on MSE itself, to check the bookmarked post I have to repeat steps 2 and 3. This to check for any updates or just to consult these posts, etc.

A bookmark button for both math.SE and math.meta.SE below the "Home" link on the left hand side space of the main page would greatly help.

Another better alternative would be to provide [image: Bookmark] button alongside [image: Options] option buttons with [image: Dropdown] drop-down.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Good idea but probably not going to get implemented :c

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational This is a community run website so if quality numbers are in favour of such a proposition then it would be given a serious thought by the devs and if they see no harm in it, it will ultimately happen. Being pessimistic about it instead of optimistic is not "beautifully irrational" [XD, ;) ].

Comment: Is this specifically for mobile? For questions visited not too long ago, the browser tends to remember them and when I type a bit of URL, the link is offered among the suggestions. (For example, if I put "list comm" in the browser, I am offered List of comment templates as one of the suggestions.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak if the changes do take place then they would reflect in mobile brower/app too but I'm generally using my laptop. I don't find myself very comfortable on mobile. Anyways, such a feature would definitely provide convenience to mobile users too. Don't you agree?

Comment: @InanimateBeing I neither agree nor disagree. I just mentioned what I am typically using when I want to get to a post that I visited frequently - I assume that using the same would be cumbersome on mobile.

Comment: Here is a feature request on Meta Stack Overflow that seems a bit similar: [Move/Add Favorites Tab to Homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376918). (It is from 2018, score is 4 at the moment.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you, but do we have "Favorites" tab? If not, then maybe it's outdated? Though the pic used there is great.

Comment: @InanimateBeing AFAICT the "favorites tab" mentioned in that post is the one [available on your profile page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1050858/inanimatebeing?tab=bookmarks) - so the same one you're mentioning in this feature request. (If you prefer, we can [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/8/3) - so that we do not leave too many comments here.)

Comment: Nein , das ist kein problem @InanimateBeing