# Prompt OP to answer their own question?

Tags: discussion, comment, self-answer, best-practices

Sometimes I find questions (*e.g*. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756314/finding-solution-of-non-homogeneous-ode-when-we-know-the-solutions-of-the-homoge)) where after some back-and-forth in the comments OP answers their own question and appends their final answer to their question. In the interest of minimizing the number of unanswered questions on the site, is it good practise to leave a comment prompting OP to type up their work as a proper answer, which they can then accept?

Comment: Yes, and many users do that often.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you! Were it not for the irony, I'd be tempted to ask you to make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To quote user Arctic Char:

> Yes, and many users do that often.

Indeed, we have made a [comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9890/629362) for such a situation. The following can be directly copied and pasted.

`@... If you found the answer to your question, please consider self-answering your question, so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).`

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of that page of comment templates - I'll be bookmarking that.

Comment: +1, definitely appreciate having a template!