# Looking for template which says something like "the way of saying thank you is upvoting or accepting an answer"

Tags: support, comment

I saw a question here on Meta with several templates but not the one I need. I remember seeing sometime ago a template that read more or less like: "the way of saying thank you here is upvoting or accepting an answer" but in a more tactful way.

Comment: What's wrong with [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4945/39599)?

Comment: @Micheal Albanese: Good question: it only mentions accepting but not upvoting and also it  does not point that "thank you" is not a substitute for accepting/upvote. If I don't find what I am looking for I will use this one since it is somewhat close.

Comment: What about [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276179/inequality-problem-algebra#comment610372_276179)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Perfect, very polite and in the spirit I needed.

Comment: `Welcome to this site! [Accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers are good ways to say thanks; these actions signal resolution, prevent the page from being bumped, score points, and influence the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.`$\quad$

Comment: `Welcome to this site! If the issue has been resolved, do consider [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers: this signals resolution, prevents the page from being bumped, scores points, and influences the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.`$\quad$

Comment: `Users who [accept ✔ good answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to their past questions are more likely to have their future questions answered.`$\quad$