# When to raise flag above 5k reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, accepted-answer

I have a 5k reputation and so what are the cases where I should use flag because I have some of my flags declined.

Secondly, there are some answers where the questioner didn't accept my answer in spite of commenting and asking whether he/she has any difficulties in understanding the question or not. Is there any way to get the acceptance there. When I was younger in math stack I faced the same issue and out of anger, I downvoted the question. What happened that he downvoted my answer too. Now being experienced I don't encourage doing this kind of silly things. Still, I am in search of a way. Should I raise a flag in these cases?

Comment: Even the moderators cannot force someone to accept the answer, so flagging seems very useless.

Comment: Hmm, even I was thinking that. Then there is no way. Am I right?

Comment: see the comments to this related post: [looking-for-template-which-says-something-like-the-way-of-saying-thank-you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16405/looking-for-template-which-says-something-like-the-way-of-saying-thank-you-is-u)

Comment: There are many related posts you can find by searching "accepting an answer" on meta.  You'll note, upon submitting your search, that sometimes users feel conflicted accepting any one answer (only one can be accepted per post) because they found two or more answers most helpful.  If you decide to post a comment, do so only below the question (and not below your answer), do not suggest the asker accept your answer in particular, (e.g., refer to accepting *an* answer, and not accepting *my* answer.  ...

Comment: ...Perhaps most importantly, if you carefully comment, via a mere link, or a fairly well received template, I suggest you occasionally do the same on a few posts that you **did not** answer, but other(s) did, and yet no answer is yet accepted.  These are meant to be suggestions to think about.  There is no mse stipulation that you can't leave a comment encouraging an asker to accept "an" answer.  I'm simply pointing out common themes regarding the use of comments to prompt a user.  Make it the least self-serving as you can.

Comment: Yeah I am getting it but I am saying about the questions where I am the only one to answer and the question was pretty straight forward e.g https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667401/rolles-theorem-application/2667404#2667404.

Comment: Regarding the flags: you raise a lot of issues in flags that you should deal with yourself (or ignore). If a post needs editing, edit it or tell the user in a comment to do it. If a post needs to be close, vote to close it. Etc. You should **not** signal generic issues with posts via  flags. You should also not try to communicate with the post owner via flags. Use a comment instead.

Comment: Each flag (excepting duplicate and moderator intervention) explains when to use that flag and has a link to the help information. Have you read those links? What about their explanations is unclear to you?

Comment: But there is another answer given at your linked post. Any way, you answered three hours ago, the other answer came 2 hours ago, and *the question you link was posted only roughly three hours ago.  Pressuring the asker to accept an answer any earlier than a day (I'd suggest at least two days before doing so) is unjustifiable, as far as I see it.  You have to allow for others to answer, for the askers right to wait, hoping for a better answer, e.g.

Comment: Yes, you are right and after that I get concerned. So I posted it with all my doubts.

Comment: Some of the unclear parts are said in the questions. In particular, I was trying to get 'Deputy' badge but now it seems to be pretty late.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, @amWhy.

Comment: Well I'm glad you posted on meta, and asked here, to get feedback and suggestions from others, @user152715.